# How to tackle this design obstacle in Qt?

Tags: c++, forms, qt, qtgui, qlayout

I need to draw a form that would have some options on the left, this can be seen in the following diagram:

[image]

Now, when a user clicks on `OptionA`, a separate related layout would be shown on the right.
and when a user clicks on `OptionB`, a separate related layout would be shown on the right.

My current design approach for such type of a problem is as follows:

Have a form with a horizontal layout with two frames. One frame has the options, while the other frame would be hosting other forms. So, in my case `optionA` would have a separate form, say formA, `OptionB` would have its own form, say formB, and `OptionC` would have its own form, say formC.

Now when ever a user clicks on `OptionA` the formA would be displayed inside FrameHost, similarly when user clicks on `OptionC`, formC would be displayed inside FrameHost. My question is if this is a good approach giving each option an independent form?

My other thought is the opposite which is to have all the forms (A, B and C) layouts inside a separate frame inside one form and when user clicks on `OptionA` the frame that has FormA content would be made visible while others would be hidden. So, one frame would be shown at a time. What would be the best approach to tackle this kind of a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is OK, but lacks the concept of [QStackWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstackedwidget.htm). I would personally use QStackedWidget for showing the forms depending on the exclusive radiobutton clicked.

The second approach is very hackish because it is trying to immitate the fact that these forms would be displayed in the same place, yet, it would render them vertically tricking on the visible/hidden property.

I would write the code like this:

```
MyWidget *formA = new MyWidget;
MyWidget *formB = new MyWidget;
MyWidget *formC = new MyWidget;

QStackedWidget *stackedWidget = new QStackedWidget;
stackedWidget->addWidget(formA);
stackedWidget->addWidget(formB);
stackedWidget->addWidget(formC);

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(stackedWidget);
setLayout(layout);

connect(myButtonGroup, SIGNAL(clicked(int)), SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
```